# Symfony phpunit testing getUser()

Tags: symfony, mocking, phpunit

how can set in test

```
$this->getUser();
```

I try to do this:

```
 $token = $this->getMockBuilder(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface::class)
                ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                ->setMethods(['getUser'])
                ->getMock();      
        $token->expects($this->any())                                                          
              ->method('getUser')                                                               
              ->willReturn($user); 

        $service = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface')
              ->disableOriginalConstructor()                                                    
              ->getMock();  
        $service->expects($this->any())                                                        
              ->method('getToken')                                                         
              ->willReturn($token);     

        $client4->getContainer()
            ->set('security.token_storage', $token);
```

I try google, but nothing help me...

Comment: Can you please be more verbose about what you’re trying to achieve?

Comment: in controller i have such line $comment->setCreatedBy($this->getUser());

Comment: and i need set to container mock or i don't know that, that when i tested this function in session will be user

Comment: i complete tested all step in my function besides this line